# call a jQuery function in for loop synchronously

Tags: javascript, jquery, synchronous

I am working on webpage where I am implementing Google maps. I want to call a jQuery function to start route on map. I am filling array using JSON. I want to call below **startRoute** function in loop but after its completion (after **startRoute**'s completion not the loop).

This **startRoute** function provide new lat,long set and I have to move animation along the path(such as real time tracking) from last location to new current location without refreshing map,TIA.

```
  for (i = 1; i < RoutePointslength; ++i) {
      var CurrentLatLong = [];                                
      CurrentLatLong.push([data._DriverLocation[i].Latitude, data._DriverLocation[i].Longitude]); 
   localStorage["EndLatLong"] = null;
   localStorage["EndLatLong"] = JSON.stringify(CurrentLatLong[0]).replace('[', '').replace(']', '');          
      setTimeout(function() { 
        startRoute(); 
      }, 300); 
    }

 function startRoute() {
        polyline = null;
        poly2 = null;
        polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: [],
            strokeColor: 'green',
            strokeWeight: 3
        });
        poly2 = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: [],
            strokeColor: 'green',
            strokeWeight: 3
        });
        // Create a renderer for directions and bind it to the map.
        var rendererOptions = {
            map: map,
            strokeColor: "#8b0013"
        };
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);

        //var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
        var start_ = localStorage["StartLatLong"]; //initial lat,long
        var end_ = localStorage["EndLatLong"];
        var travelMode = google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING;
        localStorage["StartLatLong"] = null;
        localStorage["StartLatLong"] = end_;

        var request = {
            origin: start_,
            destination: end_,
            travelMode: travelMode
        };

        // Route the directions and pass the response to a
        // function to create markers for each step.
        directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

                var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                var route = response.routes[0];
                startLocation = new Object();
                endLocation = new Object();
                // For each route, display summary information.
                var path = response.routes[0].overview_path;
                var legs = response.routes[0].legs;
                for (i = 0; i < legs.length; i++) {
                    if (i === 0) {
                        startLocation.latlng = legs[i].start_location;
                        startLocation.address = legs[i].start_address;                        
                    }
                    endLocation.latlng = legs[i].end_location;
                    endLocation.address = legs[i].end_address;
                    var steps = legs[i].steps;
                    for (j = 0; j < steps.length; j++) {
                        var nextSegment = steps[j].path;
                        for (k = 0; k < nextSegment.length; k++) {
                            polyline.getPath().push(nextSegment[k]);
                            bounds.extend(nextSegment[k]);
                        }
                    }
                }  
                polyline.setMap(map);                    
                map.fitBounds(bounds);                   
                map.setZoom(18);                  
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can modify your loop like this:

```
var mapIsMoving = false;
var CurrentLatLong = [];                                

google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function() {
    mapIsMoving = false;
});

for(var i = 0 ; i < RoutePointsLength; i++){
    if(mapIsMoving){
       i--;
       continue;
    }
    CurrentLatLong.push([data._DriverLocation[i].Latitude, data._DriverLocation[i].Longitude]); 
    localStorage["EndLatLong"] = null;
    localStorage["EndLatLong"] = JSON.stringify(CurrentLatLong[0]).replace('[', '').replace(']', '');          
    // run the route     
    startRoute();      
}
```

and on the startRoute method:

```
function startRoute() {
    mapIsMoving = true;
    polyline = null;
    poly2 = null;
...
...
...
```

Because `setTimeout` will make the method run in another thread, and therefore the loop can't detect it's completion. You need to run it on the same thread to block the loop to execute the next route drawing.

Comment: nope its not working i had tried it, as startRoute() will create line on route and move animation, at completion of loop I have multiple startRoute functions and all starts working together, I want to call it after prevoius execution..

Comment: Ok, then we need a move end event. I'll check for that.

Comment: I meant `seperate execution context`. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/314773/does-settimeout-really-execute-in-parallel. No need for downvote.

Comment: thanks @Taha, closer to the solution but still not completed, though upvote for you..